# How to derive generic class from base generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a base abstract generic class

```
public abstract class A<T> where T: Control
{
    protected T _t { get; set; }

    protected abstract void Method ();

    protected A(T t)
    {
        _t = t;
    }
}
```

B class is derived from A with type TreeView

```
public class B<T>: A<TreeView>
{
    protected override void Method ()
    {
        _t.CallSomeTreeViewMethod (); // ok!
    }

    public B (TreeView tree): base (tree)
    {

    }
}
```

How to derive from B class with type which is derived from TreeView?

```
public class C: B<ExtendedTreeView>
{
    protected override void Method ()
    {
        _t.CallSomeExtendedTreeViewMethod ();
    }

    public C (ExtendedTreeView tree): base (tree)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the `T` parameter of your class `B<T>` is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of concrete class `TreeView` add a generic constraint:

```
public class B<T>: A<T> where T:TreeView
{
    protected override void Method ()
    {
        _t.CallSomeTreeViewMethod (); // ok!
    }

    public B (T tree): base (tree)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It is like delegating and refining the type constraints of the preceding type signature to another subtype's signature in the type hierarchy.

Comment: How to instantiated the base class in the derived? Can  you look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61435054/841330). Note I will delete this comment later.

Comment: @zar, all instantiation in .net is done by constructors. constructor of a derived class calls constructor of the base class (all of them). I don't know `c++ cli` and don't understand the issue with code in that post