# How to instantiate a generic base class in derived class in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am new to generics. My derived class need to pass the generic type to base class. My derived class itself doesn't need generic type.

```
class A { public: }; 

generic < typename T>
public ref class Base
{
public:
    T m_Instance;

    void Hello()
    {
        cout << "Base::Hello() called" << endl;
    }

    T GetInstance()
    {
        return m_Instance;
    }

};


public ref class Derived :  Base <A>
{
public:

    void Print()
    {
        cout << "Derived::Print called" << endl;

        Hello();
    }
};
```

As you can you can see, my derived case knows what's the generic type for base class but I I don't know how can it derive from it and proving the type?

The application look like this and as you can see the Derived class itself doesn't use a generic type externally.

```
int main(cli::array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Derived d;

    d.Print(); 
}
```

Comment: `My derived class need to pass the generic type to base class.` Why? It's not immediately obvious what point the posted code is trying to make.

Comment: @dxiv The posted code just illustrates the problem.

Comment: *What* problem? It helped if you added a comment somewhere like "*this is what would need to happen here, but it doesn't work because ...*".

Comment: @dxiv I was following this [article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/creating-ccli-wrapper/)  which uses this technique to create wrapper class.

Comment: Please spell out what the question exactly is that you mean to ask here.

Comment: @dxiv I have demonstrated that in simplest way already. You asked for context, I provided you that.

Comment: Before context, what is unclear is the question itself. The title does not match the posted code, which does not "*instantiate a generic base class in derived class*" anywhere. The "*I don't know how can it derive from it and proving the type*" part doesn't parse well. Both the base and derived classes know the "*generic type*" already (`A::typeid` and `T::typeid` respectively), so there is no "*need to pass the generic type to base class*" either.